# Not able to apply styles/class in vue js while using it in loop

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here is my code. item.fav is initially false, but when I click on button it becomes true, I want color of icon to be purple when item.fav is true. But this is not working.

```
 <template>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
         <v-col v-for="(item, index) in items">
          <v-btn icon @click='changeFav(item)'>
           <v-icon :style='{color:`${fillcolor(item)}`}'>mdi-heart</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
         </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </template>
<script>
 export default {
  ....,
  methods: {
   fillcolor(item){
    return item.fav ? 'purple' : 'orange';
   },
   changeFav(item){
     item.fav=true;
   },
  }
</script>
```

I have also tried using class

```
.....
<v-icon class='{fillColor: item.fav}'>mdi-heart</v-icon>
.....

<style>
.fillColor {
color: 'purple';
}
</style>
```

when using a data variable as condition variable it works, but I cannot use it here as I'm having a loop.

What is that I'm doing wrong here or how can I do it better?

Comment: Take a look at [Class and Style Bindings](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes)

Comment: Try maybe simply using `:style='{color:`${item.fav ? "purple" : "orange"}`}'`. I think that your current solution isn't working because methods aren't automatically re-evaluated when  some of it's values or parameters change. It's just called once when the component is initially rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Class and Style Bindings](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#array-syntax)

[Here is an example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script setup>
  import {ref} from 'vue'
const changeFav = (item) => {
     item.fav = !item.fav;
   }

const items = ref([
  {name: "test1", fav: false},
  {name: "test2", fav: false},
  {name: "test3", fav: true},
  {name: "test4", fav: false},
  {name: "test5", fav: false},
  {name: "test6", fav: false},
  {name: "test7", fav: false},
])
</script>

<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" @click="changeFav(item)" >
    <span :class="[item.fav ? 'orange' : 'purple']">
      {{item.name}}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<style >
  .purple {
    color: purple;
  }
  .orange {
    color: orange;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your `fillcolor` method needs to run on each click, but instead you are calling the `changeFav` method which only triggers the `item.fav` and the `fillcolor` method never runs.

So, You need to call that function too by changing your code to this:

```html
<v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <v-btn icon @click="changeFav(item)">
            <v-icon :style="{ color: `${fillcolor(item)}` }">mdi-heart</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
```

```js
export default {
  ....,
methods: {
    fillcolor(item) {
      return item.fav ? "purple" : "orange";
    },

    changeFav(item) {
      item.fav = true;
      return this.fillcolor(item)
    },
  },
}
```

================================================================
But I would prefer to do it like this:

```html
 <template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <v-btn icon @click="item.fav = !item.fav">
            <v-icon :color="item.fav ? 'purple': 'red'">mdi-heart</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Although, it really depends on the way you are handling your data. For example, if you are using `vuex` then you should consider using `mutations`. I assumed you have the items and can handle them simply like this:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { name: "t1", fav: false },
      { name: "t2", fav: false },
      { name: "t3", fav: false },
      { name: "t4", fav: false },
      { name: "t5", fav: false },
      { name: "t6", fav: false },
      { name: "t7", fav: false },
    ],
  }),
};
```